# Yii2 Advanced application Deployment Steps?

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

How to deploy Yii2 advanced application on server?

I've try steps given [in these link](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/tutorial-shared-hosting.md) but still by frontend/web/index.php show blank page?

I'm new in Yii2. Please give the steps for deployment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you found the application is not deployed. then check or search for error_log file which is show you the exact error in which file.

Below is the path where **error_log** file will be find:

1. in your root application
2. in frontend/web/
3. in backend/web/